# Discord Bot Py Can't Kick Member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to make a kick command, and everything worked great, until I started adding some extra messages in case of a user error, and now I can only figure out how to kick member, but messages don't work and get messages to work, but the bot is not kicking members.

Basically, if I write `members: discord.Member`, bot kicks users, but do not display the messages, and if I write `commands.Greedy[discord.Member]`, it's the other way around.

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)  
async def kick(ctx, members : commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *,reason=None):
    if not members:
      await ctx.send("** You need to name someone to kick **")
      return
   
    for member in members:
        if bot.user == member:
            embed = discord.Embed(title = "You can't kick me, I'm an almighty bot")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)   

    await members.kick(reason=reason)
```

Sorry if it was already asked, did not seem to find the solution for me.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You are missing a `return` after the second error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `members` variable is a list, you need to kick them in the for loop

```py
for member in members:
    if member == bot.user:
        await ctx.send("You can't kick me")
    else:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
```